# Will DAOS increase DIIOP performance?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

One of our NSFs is about 50GB in size, and DAOS is turned off.
I often have to extract data out of it using DIIOP, and it takes solid 5 minutes just to start extracting data from a @Modified based formula (incremental loads).

I was thinking that maybe enabling DAOS will reduce the file size and make the "query" faster. Is that assumption correct?

Running 8.5.3 FP3 on Windows x64

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using the @Modified function in a  Database.search() method. That should only be looking at note headers. Please show the entire search formula. Also, how many documents are in the database?

Comment: SELECT #Modified >= #TextToTime(startdate) & #Modified < #TextToTime(enddate); I replaced the @ with # because it thinks I'm tagging users haha. Anyway, that's my formula, it runs a database with a little bit over 1M documents. Takes about 4 minutes to start pulling data - building the result set, I would assume.

Answer (score 2):

Database size is a measure of three main dimensions: documents, views and attachments. You could use **Manage Views** in Domino Administrator to find out how much space view indexes are using. As for attachments, you could rely on **DAOS Estimator Tool** to measure on that number.

Generally speaking, shrinking a database result in faster operations. If attachments take most of the database, DAOS could be a good alternative.

By the way, I'm kind of interested in how this change would behave in a heavy loaded environment. If you don't mind, please post some **before and after** data.

Comment: I gave you +1 for the Manage Views idea, it's really worth looking at. Based on the formula I pasted as a comment below the question, do you think there's a view that could be built which the Formula could benefit from? By the way, here is a pastebin with the daosest results: http://pastebin.com/Hp1ZcMGS

Comment: Adding a view with @Modified in the first sorted column and using the NoteView class, the NotesView.GetEntryByKey(startdate) and NotesView,CreateNavigatorFrom methods, and then using the NotesViewNavigator class to walk through the entries until you get to enddate will almost certainly be faster.

Comment: Well, I'm actually using Talend with tNotesInput connector, and I've never used pure Java to connect to notes. On the bright side, it uses Notes.jar. So besides the coding which I don't really want to rewrite, all I have to do is create a view for all my docs with the first column as @Modified and make it sorted? Do I have to add columns for all the fields I am loading, or the engine will use the index and scan the NoteIDs from there? Sorry if I sound confused, I'm actually a little! Does that make sense?

Comment: You would only add columns for items to identify the documents, unless the number of items being loaded was fairly small (<10). The NotesViewEntry has access to the NotesDocument to get the other items. View traversing is VERY fast until you go at the NotesDocument so this is somewhat a balancing act.

Another approach would be, if the Domino server is running the HTTP task is to create a Bean with XPages that can do the traversing for you and send the results via JSON or XML. The BEAN can be called using XPages REST services which have exceptional caching processes.